# Are tourists in New Caledonia safer from terrorism than in metropolitan France?

Tags: france, safety, new-caledonia

I haven't heard about any recent terrorist attacks in New Caledonia (there was one back in [1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouv%C3%A9a_cave_hostage_taking), but that had government members as hostages, as opposed to tourists or other ordinary bystanders). However, this could just be because it has a smaller population than metropolitan France, rather than a lower per capita risk of terrorism.

Reunion Island, a different French overseas territory, had a suspected terrorist [wounding two police](http://www.france24.com/en/20170427-two-police-wounded-islamist-frances-reunion-island?ref=tw_i) in April 2017.

The demographics of New Caledonia are somewhat but not greatly different from those of metropolitan France.

Is there information indicating that New Caledonia is safer for tourists with regards to terrorism than metropolitan France?

Comment: Is this question regarded as offensive, paranoid, or poorly researched?

Comment: The close reason states that it is primarily opinion based. Not that close reasons are always meaningful. But in this case it makes sense.

Comment: 'The demographics of New Caledonia are somewhat but not greatly different from those of metropolitan France.' What?  Can you source this?  They look very different to me: https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/nc.html https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/fr.html

Comment: @tompreston I looked again, and they still look somewhat but not greatly different.

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of "somewhat", but between 55-70% of the population in new caledonia are south east asian or pacific islanders, the overwhelming majority of people in france are european or north african.  That seems very different to me.

Answer (score 6):

As terrorism is crazy acts by crazy people, some designed and many rather random, you can not predict it.
There are parts of the world where it is more likely to run into terorism, but France nor New Caledonia is on the high risk list.

People going to a small island in safe Norway got killed by one person who handled in an unpredictable way.
That can happen anywhere in the world, so also in safe New Caledonia.

In Paris, where the risk of a terrorist attacks is more likely, there is safety in numbers. Even if many people suffer in an attack in Paris, the chances you are not involved are huge, it is very likely you will not even notice anything till services are stopped or police comes out on the streets in force.

Anyway, if you let terrorist dictate where you can or can not travel, they win. I will not let them win, so I have been in Paris and will travel to Paris again when the chance comes up.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It does in that it is impossible to calculate either set of risks, so that it is impossible to give a schale.

Comment: Disingenuous. Terrorism cannot be predicted in Afghanistan or Iraq or Reykjavik. Your argument seems to suggest a tourist will be equally in danger from terrorist acts no matter which of those three destinations they choose for their next holiday.

Comment: @hippietrail The two destinations given in the question are both on a relative even level, not like Afganistan against Iceland. But I will add a few words to the answer.

Comment: @hippietrail, I also feel there is a distinction between regularly reoccuring violence and terrorism where the attacks are like thunder under a clear sky, totally unpredictable. To me the question is asking about that last situation, not like visiting a country where there is war or has been a war which while officialy at peace, the warring parties are still commiting war actions.

Comment: @Willeke: I agree it's a bad question, but because it's asking for discussion and opinions and the answer is an obvious "probably but you never can be too sure". The answer does read better now too. I removed my downvote.

Answer (score -2):

Yes and no

## Yes, it is safer

Because [New Caledonia is somehow independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Caledonia#Status). Combine with the fact that even France do not care for this remote island it makes NC an ultra-low priority target

## No, no place is safe

Because the word of ISIS is like "Strike them in your neighborhood"
This means that if a guy living there feel like killing people for ISIS, he will kill people in New Caledonia. Even if it is meaningless on the big picture (he can't do anything on the big picture anyway)

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?